# Livewire Alpinejs Emit/Dispatch variables across files

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

**How can I emit and recognise changes from child components (in separated files) using AlpineJS?**

I'm trying to build a form in Livewire/alpinejs that would only show the next step after selected a value in the previous step.

I know I can use livewire model/emitUp to catch changes from the selectfield child component and then use x-show accordingly. However, emitting up is rather slow, waiting around 5 seconds after selecting each select field isn't a good user experience. Hence the user of AlpineJs.

The issue is that x-data is scoped locally and I cannot pass down a variable and assign that as the x-model. AlpineJS has $dispatch, but it seems to only work within a file. So I can't dispatch when the x-model changed and then catch that change in Livewire Main Form.

Livewire Main Form

```
<div>
  <form>
    <livewire:selectfield />

    {{-- Only show this div when livewire:selectfield has selected a value (Incomplete code)--}}
    <p> 
      Should see this only when a select-field value has been selected 
    </p>
  </form>
<div>
```

Livewire Select Field

```
<div x-data="{ selectedField: '' }">
  <label> Form Label </label>
  <select x-model="selectedField">
    <option value="1">Opt 1</option>
    <option value="2">Opt 2</option>
    <option value="3">Opt 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Is there any way of showing/hiding div elements when the child component input fields have a selected input? Preferably with AlpineJS due for user experience and less network bombardments.

**EDIT**

Turns out I just didn't use the functions properly! Ignore this

Answer (score 0):

Must of read the docs wrong. Using Livewire/AlpineJS can emit values from child to parent, similar to VueJS.

The child component HTML should have

```
<button type="button" @click="$dispatch('custom-event')">Test Model Update Upwards</button>
```

The parent component has this html. In your case, just add the custom event where it makes sense.

```
<p @custom-event.window="console.log('Workign emit function cross child/parent')"></p>
```